# ¿Cómo indicar que utilice la interfaz host en docker-compose version 3.3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cluster

Buenas tardes a todos.

Estoy haciendo un cluster de dos raspberry pi con docker utilizando docker-compose.

Pero necesito sabe como poner en el compose que se use en modo host los servicios.

Este es mi compose:

```html
version: "3.3"

services:
  miservicio_dhcp:
    image: blanrok/dhcpins2
    ports:
      - 67:67
      - 68:68
    tty: true

  miservicio_dns:
    image: blanrok/dnsins2
    ports:
      - 53:53
    tty: true
```

usando el comando docker stack deploy

Un saludo, Espero vuestra respuesta :), gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).

Si usas *docker stack deploy* necesitaras tener los docker en modo swarm.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo 1 manager y otro worker en el cluster, ya unidos. Lo siguiene que hago es ejecutar el comando docker stack deploy compose-file=docker-compose.yml y ahí es donde me da el problema con el parametro network_mode: host.

Segun he estado leyendo network_mode es incompatible con el comando docker stack deploy. ¿Hay alguna forma de poder usarlo, o existe algun parametro equivalente para este comando?

Answer (score 0):

Si, eso lo se y esta hecho. pero me dice que al usar el comando docker stack deploy para poner todos los contenedores en el cluster con el archivo docker-compose, el parametro network_mode que me permite acceder a mi lan con HOST, es incompatible. ¿Y no hay otra forma para enlazar los contenedores con mi red real?

Comment: no habras respuestas a tu pregunta, si quieres opinar, aclarar... sobre una respuesta o pregunta mejor utiliza "añadir comentario". En tu pregunta inicial comentabas como poenrlo en modo HOST. Es el comando que te especificado, pero como comentas, posiblemente es incompatible con stack deploy. No tengo claro exactamente, que es lo que quieres hacer... ¿Estas intentando que tus contenedores esten conectados en la misma red de docker, dentro del swarm?

Comment: Ya lo he averiguado. La solucion está en poner el docker-compose en versión 3.3 y añadir en el final del fichero networks: outside: external: name: "host", además quitar los ports del fichero ya que al añadir esas lineas al fichero, el sistema obvia los puertos. si se dejan los puertos da un mensaje de error. Esa era la solución